# How to inner join two tables with levenstein conditional statement and using percentages

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

The following script returns what I am looking for which is an inner join looking for data that are similar in the two tables.

```
SELECT zip_codes.building_name, test_1_2.poiname_c_132, zip_codes.street_name, test_1_2.streetname_c_35 FROM zip_codes INNER JOIN test_1_2
 ON (levenshtein(replace(zip_codes.building_name, ' ',''),replace(test_1_2.poiname_c_132, ' ',''))
  < 2)
  AND
   (levenshtein(replace(zip_codes.street_name, ' ',''),replace(test_1_2.streetname_c_35, ' ',''))
    < 4);
```

After that I tried to get fancy and make the inner join return a percentage that needed to be lower than the percentage found to be joined but I am not getting the correct output

```
SELECT zip_codes.building_name, test_1_2.poiname_c_132, zip_codes.street_name, test_1_2.streetname_c_35 FROM zip_codes INNER JOIN test_1_2
 ON (levenshtein(replace(zip_codes.building_name, ' ',''),replace(test_1_2.poiname_c_132, ' ',''))
 /GREATEST(char_length(replace(test_1_2.poiname_c_132,' ','')), char_length(replace(zip_codes.building_name,' ','')))
  < 2/GREATEST(char_length(replace(test_1_2.poiname_c_132,' ','')), char_length(replace(zip_codes.building_name,' ',''))))
  AND
   (levenshtein(replace(zip_codes.street_name, ' ',''),replace(test_1_2.streetname_c_35, ' ',''))/GREATEST(char_length(replace(test_1_2.streetname_c_35,' ','')), char_length(replace(zip_codes.street_name,' ','')))
    < 4/GREATEST(char_length(replace(test_1_2.streetname_c_35,' ','')), char_length(replace(zip_codes.street_name,' ',''))));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing sounds like a recipy for a very, very slow query. You are effectively calculating the levenshtein distance between all combinations of records in the tables. If you know 10.000 zipcodes and have 1000 records in the other table, the databse will have to parse 10.000.000 combinations, calculating the levenshtein four times per combination...

If the levenshtein must be within two characters distance then the stings cannot differ in length more than two characters either. Given that most stringswill differ much more, you can elimiate them before even going to levenshtein, using a fast and indexeable WHERE condition.

As for your question about percentages, what exectly do you want to end up with? All combinations that differ less than X percent for both fields?

Comment: How would I add that WHERE condition in...(Noob im sorry)

Comment: This editor is killing me :-)

You would simply tell the database what the condition is: The difference on length may not be more than two, so length(table_a.field) - length(table_b.field) may not be more than 2 or less than -2.

Something like:
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.something =b.something
WHERE ABS(length(a.field)-length(b.field))<=2